# Hyperledger Fabric byfn instantiate fails - chaincode exists

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hi All I have a 3 peer 1 orderer organization running and I want to bring the network down and clear ledgers while keeping the crypto. Here is what I have run to bring network down:

**first on orderer:**
  docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml down --volumes

**Then on peers:**
  - docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml -f docker-compose-couch.yaml down 
     --volumes

- docker-compose -f docker-compose-kafka.yaml down --volumes
- docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq) && docker rmi -f $(docker images | grep "dev\|none\|test-vp\|peer[0-9]-" | awk '{print $3}')

one peers all volumes are not present even with "docker ps -aq". Therefore I bring the network up with all the docker-compose up commands on each peer.

Finally on the orderer when I run ./byfn.sh up it runs fine until instantiate then fails with chaincode exists..

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete couchdb too because chaincode information can be inside.
Have you try ?

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq) && docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi -chaincode-
```

If you want to keep the data of the ledger(and so not delete the couchdb) you can also do a simple upgrade chaincode instead of instantiate (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/chaincode4noah.html#upgrade)

Comment: docker ps -aq does not show anything when I run it after bringing down all peers and commands shown above. Therefore the above would not remove anything

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed. I had to first remove the ./couch folder where the data is stored, and increase the timer of peer channel create to 10 seconds in script.sh when running byfn up.